# What is the best way to pass int[] to the view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Noticed a problem, when I pass my model to the view, one of the properties of type int[] transforms into

```
<input type="hidden" value="System.Int32[]" name="test">
```

I'd expect to see stringified values of the array in the value property.
I tried to use  List. Which resulted into:

```
<input type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" 
       name="test">
```

I have quite complex Model, which depends on other classes, that is why I don't want to change it to string format. Is it not possible to use int[] ?

Comment: How you are assigning the values? Provide that source code. it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Can you provide the source code for the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `.ToString()` value of the types which for more complex types is the type name.

Can you expose your collection properties in a different way. i.e.

```
public int [] MyIntegers
{
   ...
}

public string MyIntegersStringified
{
    get {

       return string.Join(",", MyIntegers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would need to receive the values back to another action method via POST, you have to write your own code in the view that creates the HTML like this (one hidden field for each item in the list):

```
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="test[0]">
<input type="hidden" value="345" name="test[1]">
```

Read this for more information: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the view you may need to do something like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Array, new { value = String.Join(",", Model.Array) })
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.HiddenFor` accepts an object as the value.  What you are seeing is the `object.ToString()`, which for an Int32 array is the name of the type: "System.Int32[]".

If you want to simple store a csv version of your array in a hidden field, you could try the following:

```
@Html.Hidden("test", string.Join(",", values))
```